# Preimage of exponential map

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Consider a Lie group $G$ and a Lie subgroup $H$ of $G$. Denote their corresponding Lie algebras by $\mathfrak g$ and $\mathfrak h$, respectively. Then we have an exponential map $\exp:\mathfrak g\to G$, and its restriction to $\mathfrak h$ gives a map $\exp:\mathfrak h\to H$.

I wonder about the following: If $\alpha\in\mathfrak g$ is such that $\exp(\alpha)\in H$, does it necessarily follow that $\alpha\in\mathfrak h$? In other words, for the exponential map $\exp:\mathfrak g\to G$, do we have $\exp^{-1}(H)=\mathfrak h$?

I feel like this is used quite often in arguments, yet this property was never stated explicitly beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not true. For instance, take $G=GL_2(\Bbb R)$, $H=\left\{\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1&t\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right]\,\middle|\,t\in\Bbb R\right\}$, and $\alpha=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}0&-2\pi\\2\pi&0\end{smallmatrix}\right]$. Then $\alpha\in\mathfrak{gl}_2(\Bbb R)$ and $\exp(\alpha)=\operatorname{Id}\in H$. However, $\alpha\notin\mathfrak h$.

On the other hand, it is true that$$(\forall t\in\Bbb R):\exp(t\alpha)\in H\implies\alpha\in\mathfrak h.$$

Comment: How can I check your last claim?

Comment: The map $\gamma\colon\Bbb R\longrightarrow H$ defined by $\gamma(t)=\exp(t\alpha)$ is a differentiable curve and $\gamma(0)=e_H$. Therefore, $\gamma'(0)\in T_{e_H}H=\mathfrak h$.